# Почему программа останавливается на строке driver = webdriver.Firefox(...)? Без ошибок, просто зависает на ней

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy, firefox

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType, Proxy

with open('proxy', 'r') as f:
    array = f.read().splitlines()

for _ in range(10):
    prox = Proxy()
    prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
    prox.http_proxy = array[_]
    prox.socks_proxy = array[_]
    prox.ssl_proxy = array[_]
    capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities, executable_path='/home/alexandr/geckodriver')
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    try:
        driver.get("https://2ip.ru/")
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.quit()
    time.sleep(7)
```

Открывается браузер с пустой адресной строкой и ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте еще раз свой драйвер. Скорее всего у вас устаревшая версия, на данный момент актуальна 26.

wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux32.tar.gz